# ember.js: Specify a component inside controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have two different form components. Depending on what is chosen in a dropdown menu, I want to use a different component.

How do I specify inside a controller (where I observe the dropdown change) which component shall be called inside the according template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1) Set a property on your controller and use an if i.e in controller.js

```
dropdownChange: function() {
  if(stuff) {
    this.set('useComponentOne', true);
  } else {
    this.set('useComponentOne', false);
  }
}.observes('...')
```

And in template

```
{{#if useComponentOne}}
  {{componentOne}}
{{else}}
  {{componentTwo}}
{{/if}}
```

2) Use component binding, i.e. in controller.js

```
dropdownChange: function() {
  if(stuff) {
    this.set('componentName', 'One');
  } else {
    this.set('componentName', 'Two');
  }    
}.observes('...')
```

and in template

```
{{component componentName}}
```

Comment: `observes` here is the "computed-property-as-observer" anti-pattern. Just make `useComponentOne` or `componentName` a computed property.